# Como verificar se o caractere que eu digitei é uma letra ou número no MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

sou iniciante em programação MIPS (utilizo o MARS), meu professor pediu para que fizéssemos um programa onde dado 9 dígitos de um CPF ele calcula os dois últimos dígitos deste CPF. O programa tá funcionando, porém meu programa crasha quando eu entro com uma letra, meu professor quer que o programa trate quando o usuário entrar com uma letra, mas não sei como fazer isso, como eu comparo o valor digitado pelo usuário com todas as letras do alfabeto? Poderia fazer uma condição para cada letra do alfabeto minúscula ou maiúscula, porém não acho que essa seja a melhor forma de se fazer isso.

O problema inicial é que eu uso uma "função" para ler inteiros no programa, então se uma letra é digitada ele dá um erro direto.

```
li $v0, 5            #comando para ler um inteiro
syscall              #chamando o sistema para executar as instruções
la $t2, 0($v0)
```

Utilizo o código acima, a verificação viria depois dele e eu compararia o $t2 para saber se é uma letra ou não, mas esse código só funciona para ler inteiro, então se eu digito uma letra ele pára imediatamente!

Desde já agradeço por qualquer dica que vocês tenham para me dar!

Answer (score -2):

Eu trabalho com python, mas a ideia é a mesma, pegue cara caractere, um por um e transforma em código ASCII, cada caractere tem um sequência, por exemplo do número 0-9, em ASCII representa de ex:"60-69" , então faz um teste, se o caractere escolhido transformado em ASCII for maior que 60 e menor que 69, ele é número inteiros.

Esse método pode ser usado para vários testes, se é string ou não, é se caractere especial etc...